# i3-gaps doesn’t apply to one window

Tags: window-manager, i3, tiling-wm

I am relatively new to window managers and I got into i3 after an installation of Manjaro, through Manjaro Architect.

Gaps are working properly when two or more windows are opened, but with only one, they are not showing. How could apply i3-gaps to a single windows as well?

I'll post the images of the i3 config file, generated by Manjaro, of i3-gaps:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your config file, you need to remove (or comment) the `smart_gaps on` configuration command.

As stated in the above comment taken directly from your screenshot

```
# Smart gaps (gaps used if only more than one container on the workspace)
smart_gaps on
```

So i3-gaps is actually working as expected.